# TypeError: only length 1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding : utf-8 -*-

from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import spdiags,csr_matrix
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


u_basic=input("Signal elements (row complex vector, each element last tb sec) = ? ") ;
m_basic = u_basic.shape[1]; #gives the no. of columns
fcode = input("Allow frequency coding (Yes=1, no=0) = ? ");

if (fcode == 1):
    f_basic = input("Frequency coding in units of 1/tb (row vector of same length) = ? ");


F=input("Maximal Doppler shift for ambiguity plot [in units of 1/Mtb] (e.g., 1)= ? ");
K=input("Number of Doppler grid points for calculation (e.g., 100) = ? ");
F=float(F);
df=F/K/m_basic;
T=input("Maximal Delay for ambiguity plot [in units of Mtb] (e.g., 1)= ? ");
N=input("Number of delay grid points on each side (e.g. 100) = ? ");
sr=input("Over sampling ratio (>=1) (e.g. 10)= ? ");
r=math.ceil(sr*(N+1)/T/m_basic);
if (r==1):
    dt=1;
    m=m_basic;
    uamp=np.abs(u_basic);
    phas=uamp*0;
    phas=angle(u_basic);
    if (fcode==1):
        phas=phas+2*numpy.pi*cumsum(f_basic);

    uexp=exp(j*phas);
    u=uamp*uexp;

else:
    dt=1/r;
    ud=diag(u_basic);
    ao=ones([r,m_basic]);


m=m_basic*r;
u_basic=reshape(ao*ud,(1,m),order='F') #reshape(ao*ud,1,m);
uamp=np.abs(u_basic);
phas=angle(u_basic);
u=u_basic;

if (fcode == 1):
    ff=diag(f_basic);
    phas=2*numpy.pi*dt*cumsum(reshape(ao*ff,1,m))+phas;
    uexp=exp(j*phas);
    u=uamp*uexp;


'''t=arange(0,r*m_basic-1)/r;
a1=([0])
a2=([r*m_basic-1])
t1=concatenate((a1,t));tscale1=concatenate((a2,r*m_basic));
tscale1=[0 arange(0:r*m_basic-1) r*m_basic-1]/r;'''
t1=range(0,int(r*m_basic)-1);
t=[i/r for i in t1]
#t.append((r*m_basic)-1);
t1=t;
t1.insert (0,0);
tscale1=np.array(t1)
tscale1=np.reshape(tscale1,(1,tscale1.shape[0]))

dphas1=np.append(nan,diff(phas))
#dphas1=[nan,diff (phas)]
#dphas1=[nan,diff (phas,n=1,axis=0)]
myint=r/2/np.pi;
dphas=[j*myint for j in dphas1]
#dphas=[nan,diff (phas,n=1,axis=0)]*r/2/pi;
x=np.transpose(tscale1)
y=np.transpose(np.abs(uamp))
#a=np.append(0,uamp)
#b=np.append(a,0)

subplot(311)
plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=1.5)
#plot(tscale1 [0,abs(uamp),0],'linewidth',1.5)
ylabel(' Amplitude ')
axis([-inf,inf,0,1.2*amax(np.abs(uamp))])
#plt.show()

#phas1=np.append(0,phas)
subplot(312)
plot(tscale1, phas,linewidth=1.5)
axis([-inf,inf,-inf,inf])
ylabel(' Phase [rad] ')


myint1=ceil(amax(t))
dphas2=[k*myint1 for k in dphas]
subplot(313)
plot(t,dphas2,linewidth=1.5)
axis([-inf,inf,-inf,inf])
xlabel(' \itt / t_b ')
ylabel(' \itf * Mt_b ')

#plt.show()



dtau=ceil(T*m)*dt/N;
tau=around(arange(0,N,1)*dtau/dt)*dt;

f=arange(0,K,1)*df;
f=np.reshape(f,(1,f.shape[0]))
f=np.append(-fliplr(f),f);


mat1=spdiags(u,0,m+ceil(T*m),m);

u_padded=[zeros(1,ceil(T*m)),u,zeros(1,ceil(T*m))];

cidx=arange(1,m+ceil(T*m)+1);
ridx=around(tau/dt);
#ridx=around(tau/dt).transpose();

index = cidx[int(np.ones((N+1,1))),:]+ridx[:,int(np.ones(1,m+np.ceil(T*m)))]
#index = cidx(np.ones(N+1,1),:) + ridx(:,np.ones(1,m+ceil(T*m)));

mat2 = csr_matrix(u_padded(index));

uu_pos=mat2*mat1;
```

**I got the following error in the following line :
--> 124 index = cidx[int(np.ones((N+1,1))),:]+ridx[:,int(np.ones(1,m+np.ceil(T*m)))]
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
inputs are : np.mat([1,2,3]) , 0, 1,100,1 , 100,10**

Comment: It's pretty obvious that 90% of this code isn't at all relevant to the problem. It's not at all obvious _which_ 90% isn't relevant. Can you give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of dumping all of your code on us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int(np.ones((N+1,1)))` - `int()` is a python function that converts it's input into 1 integer.  But you give it a numpy array, a 2d one.

You probably don't need the `int`.  The `ones` need a `dtype=int` parameter.

```
np.arange(10)[np.ones((3,3),dtype=int)]
```

I agree with the comment.  Most of the code is irrelevant to this error.

```
cidx[int(np.ones((N+1,1))),:]+ridx[:,int(np.ones(1,m+np.ceil(T*m)))]
```

You might not even need the `ones` in that line.  That looks like a MATLAB expression that expands `cidx` and `ridx` so they can added together.  The use of `ones` instead of `zeros` also suggests that.  `numpy` does broadcasting, so I suspect the expression can be simplified to:

```
cidx[np.newaxis,:] + ridx[:, np.newaxis]
```

(this assumes `cidx` and `ridx` are 1d arrays - I haven't dug into the earlier code to verify this.)